# How to handle multiple on change events on drop-down selection in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem where user needs to select countries first and then states and then cities. Now I have setup @change event on countries and states, as soon as the user selects country it fetches states and also @change on states is also triggered, and since I have state_id = '', now my getCities function fails.

```
<select v-model="country_id" @change="getStates()">
    <option v-for="country in countries" :value="country.id">{{ country.name }}</option>
</select>
<select v-model="state_id" @change="getCities()">
    <option v-for="state in states" :value="state.id">{{ state.name }}</option>
</select>

data(){
    return{
        countries: [],
        states: [],
        cities: [],
        country_id: '',
        state_id: '',
        city_id: ''
    }
},
mounted(){
    getCountries();
},
methods:{
    getCountries(){
        // this.countries = response.data
    }
    geStates(){
        //get states where country_id = this.country_id
    },
    getCities(){
        //get cities where state_id = this.state_id
        //once country is selected even this is getting triggered
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check to see if the state has a value before actually getting the data.

```
getCities(){
    // Check to see if state_id has a value
    if (!this.state_id) return

    //get cities where state_id = this.state_id
    //once country is selected even this is getting triggered
}
```

Comment: Yeah I did this. But wanted to know if vuejs has an event for on selected.

Comment: @JagadeshaNH `change` is basically on selected. In this case, Vue is just using native methods.